# Speeding up random sampling for approximation of pi

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create one of the classic methods of approximating Pi, which is to "throw" darts randomly inside a square with an inscribed circle and then compute the ratio of those that landed in the circle compared to how many were thrown.

My code works, but I want to increase the number of "darts" being thrown. The problem is my code runs extremely slow. Why is that and how can I speed it up?

See my code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

darts = 2000  # number of "darts" to be thrown

r = 10  # radius/sidelength

plt.cla()

# Make a box with an inscribed circle
box = patches.Rectangle((-r,-r), 2*r, 2*r, 
                        linewidth=2, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')

circle = patches.Circle((0,0), radius=r,
                        linewidth=2, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')

inCircle = 0  # number of points that land in the circle

# Plotting
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(box)
ax.add_patch(circle)
ax.axis('equal')
plt.axis('off')

for i in range(darts):
    x = np.random.uniform(-r,r)
    y = np.random.uniform(-r,r)
    
    dist = x * x + y * y
    
    if dist <= r * r:
        inCircle += 1
        
    plt.scatter(x,y, marker='o', s=2, color = '#1f77b4')

plt.title(f'Pi Approximation with {darts} "Darts"')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig(f'PiApproximationwith{darts}darts.png', dpi = 600)
plt.show()

# Computes pi
print(Decimal(4 * inCircle/darts))
```

Comment: For feedback/suggestions on working code, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I did not know about that. I will repost there. Thank you.

Comment: Please profile your code and show us which statements are taking the majority of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the code's time is spent running the for loop so you should focus your attention there. Numpy.random.uniform can be set to return an array of given size of random numbers. By assigning 2 array types to hold 2000 variables each, you get all of your points at once. Run the for loop to see how many are in the circle and then pass those 2 arrays to the scatter plot all at once like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

darts = 2000  # number of "darts" to be thrown

r = 10  # radius/sidelength

plt.cla()

# Make a box with an inscribed circle
box = patches.Rectangle((-r, -r), 2 * r, 2 * r,
                        linewidth=2, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')

circle = patches.Circle((0, 0), radius=r,
                        linewidth=2, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')

inCircle = 0  # number of points that land in the circle

# Plotting
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(box)
ax.add_patch(circle)
ax.axis('equal')
plt.axis('off')

array_of_rand_x = np.random.uniform(-r, r, 2000)
array_of_rand_y = np.random.uniform(-r, r, 2000)

for i in range(darts):
    x = array_of_rand_x[i]
    y = array_of_rand_y[i]

    dist = x * x + y * y

    if dist <= r * r:
        inCircle += 1

plt.scatter(array_of_rand_x, array_of_rand_y, marker='o', s=2, color='#1f77b4')

plt.title(f'Pi Approximation with {darts} "Darts"')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig(f'PiApproximationwith{darts}darts.png', dpi=600)
plt.show()

# Computes pi
print(Decimal(4 * inCircle / darts))
```

Comment: The whole FOR loop is not needed here you can count the number of points in the circle by using numpy.sum: `inCircle=np.sum(array_of_rand_x**2+array_of_rand_y**2<=r**2)`. Also please use `darts` variable instead of `2000` in the definitions of the arrays to keep the code adaptable to higher number of random samples.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 suspects here:

1. `plt.scatter(x,y, marker='o', s=2, color = '#1f77b4')` - might be getting slower for each number
2. `plt.savefig(f'PiApproximationwith{darts}darts.png', dpi = 600); plt.show()` rendering of the plot. (more points to draw = more time)

Try disabling lines form point 2. and run with 1Milion darts. if the run is short you will know its the display/render